# «С амброзией предлагают бороться самой амброзией». Можно так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

**В городе Н. с амброзией предлагают бороться самой амброзией.**
То есть «министр акцентировала внимание на разработке метода борьбы с карантинным вредителем с помощью вытяжки экстрактивных масел из самой амброзии, которые уже сегодня показывают положительные результаты».
Но меня смущает согласование с глаголом «бороться». Бороться можно с кем-то, против чего-то... Как вариант, «с помощью самой амброзии»?

Answer (score 3):

Можно так говорить.

Вот множество примеров Нацкорпуса с творительным падежом: [примеры](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?spp=50&text=lexgramm&kwsz=5&sampling=1&level1=0&level2=0&spd=10&out=normal&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod1=sem&nodia=1&parent2=0&sort=i_grtagging&format=html&gramm1=inf&gramm2=S%2Cins&min2=1&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&g=i_doc&dpp=10&max2=1&sr=1&mode=main&parent1=0).

Творительный падеж указывает на инструмент борьбы.

"*С помощью*" как бы нарушает посыл фразы.
Есть похожая поговорка: *клин клином вышибают*.
Меняем: *клин с помощью клина вышибают*. || Это уже не то, что надо.

Вот красивый пример:
*И я решила: бороться до конца, бороться правдой, точным знанием своих сил.*
[С. Д. Кржижановский. Случаи (1934)]

Answer (score 1):

*В городе Н. с амброзией предлагают бороться **"самой амброзией".***

Предлагаю поставить кавычки.

Так мы подчеркнем и необычность решения, и нестандартное употребление слова.

Заголовок (или просто текст) привлечет внимание читателей, а что еще может быть важнее для  журналиста!

А вот "с помощью амброзии" – это скучно и неинтересно. К тому же это явно книжный стиль, который для описания курьезных или забавных  случаев не подходит.

Comment: Да уж... А в чём нестандартное употребление слова? Кавычки не ставятся при неправильном согласовании, так как даже с ними грамматически неверно.

Comment: Ах,  oleedd, да какая разница!  Кто будет проверять ваши падежи!  Кавычки же многозначны – каждый увидит в них то необычное и нестандартное, что захочет увидеть. Но внимание обратят все!

Comment: Кавычки были бы применимы, если бы люди не употребляли творительный падеж. А по моей ссылке видно, что он употребляется даже не редко, а в полной мере.

Comment: То люди, а это читатели журнальных статей. Им новости интересны, а не падежи :))  Чтобы понять чью-то психологию, нужно поставить себя на его место. Вои он увидел кавычки и понимает, что фраза УСЛОВНА, поэтому вряд ли будет вспоминать правила стандартной или нестандартной грамматики.

Comment: В чём условность?

Comment: Понимаете, это уже не сама амброзия в натуральном виде, а  вытяжка экстрактивных масел из нее.

Comment: В таких случаях кавычки всё равно не употребляют, по моим наблюдениям. Ну допустим, но с точки зрения логики эти масла представляют собой амброзию, только не всю. А именно слово "амброзия" указывает на **вещество**, из которого состоит растение. *Кавычки же многозначны – каждый увидит в них то необычное и нестандартное, что захочет увидеть* — этим вы меня поразили, слова истинного художника. Знаки пунктуации употребляются по какой-то причине, а не чтобы каждый нашёл в них что-то своё. Лингвистический анекдот у вас получился.

Answer (score 0):

На мой вкус, это предложение стилистически коряво.

Во-первых, глагол **бороться** если и сочетается с существительными в творительном падеже, то, как правило, только в тех случаях, когда эти существительные выражают отвлечённые понятия, а не буквальные орудия борьбы. Я нашёл всего пару исключений, которые относятся скорее к профессиональному жаргону и тоже немного режут слух с непривычки, например: "бороться руками".

Во-вторых, слово **самой** как будто специально вставлено, чтобы подчеркнуть эту корявость. Это как если сказать *клин самим клином вышибают* (но это я шучу — я понимаю, что нет ничего глупее, чем коверкать идиомы ради доказательств чего-либо).

Я согласен, что "... бороться с помощью самой амброзии" звучит намного лучше.

Comment: *клин самим клином вышибают* — звучит нормально (если не привыкать к исходной фразе)!!! *нет ничего глупее, чем коверкать идиомы ради доказательств чего-либо* — это всего лишь ваше мнение, и скорее оно относится к глупостям. Где анализ "*с помощью*"? Это лучше? Где предложенное решение?! Если у вас "непрывычка", то это не значит, что и у других тоже.

Comment: @oleedd Дополнил ответ предложенным решением. Что касается последнего Вашего замечания, так ведь я и начал с того, что "на мой вкус". Очевидно, что вкусы у профессионалов и любителей/дилетантов отличаются. Я не могу в данном случае рассуждать профессионально, а наши "привычки" основаны на нашей культуре чтения и на окружении. Понятно, что у каждого из нас они разные.

Comment: *Понятно, что у каждого из нас они разные* — это да, мне вообще творительный слух не режет. Я про решение, которое вы предлагаете (как сказать красиво).